# Opening a PDF file will open a blank PDF

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I am trying to open a PDF file (already downloaded) in Android App. I am sending ACTION.View intent. The concerned code is as follows

```
 File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()
        + File.separator + fileName);


        Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this,BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", pdfFile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        Toast.makeText(this, "hello: "+pdfFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        t1 =  findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //t1.setText(path.toString() + "####"+pdfFile.getPath());
        try{
            startActivity(pdfIntent);

        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Application available to view PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            t1.setText("No applicatoin available");
        } catch ( Exception e){
            t1.setText("No App Found sorry "+ e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "No App found, sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finally {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "This is finally block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Corresponding XML in the Manifest file is as follows

```
   <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

And the file_paths, content is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

Now it works fine to the extent that the PDF is being opened but it shows no content, and is rather blank. What I am suspecting is, the path of the PDF file may not be correct and hence it opens some dummy PDF perhaps? How do I provide correct path to application, I am particularly not sure about this line does in file_paths

```
**<external-path name="Download" path="Download"/>**
```

Can someone shed some light on it, how can I can fix it or debug it? What am I possibly doing wrong. I am new to Android development.

Here is my screen when opening PDF file which is basically blank (content is zero).

[image]

When I debug the code, the name of the path file is given as follows

> content://com.example.openpdf.provider/Download/2019_10_22_03_37_25_pm5906.pdf

which I think is the problem (this pdf file is in the download folder by the way)

Comment: What is that 2019_10_27_03_37 in the pucture?

Comment: This is the PDF file that I am opening. It is opening fine when clicked through directly via downloaded file links.

Comment: So the path is correct. pdfFile.size() or pdfFile.getSize() will tell you if the size is 0.

Comment: Your app needs permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest and at runtime.

Comment: How do I make sure the path is correct in the above code, that is what what I am suspected is wrong. The the pdf file is in "download" folder.

Comment: Yes that permission are there, all of it. And that's why it does open the file but it is blank.

Comment: Also try pdfFile.exists().

Comment: I may try this and that's where the problem is, I guess, but I need help to specify correct path to the file

Comment: When I debug the code, the path of the PDF file is given to me as follows "content://com.example.openpdf.provider/Download/2019_10_22_03_37_25_pm5906.pdf" which does not make sense to me.

Comment: That is the value of the Uri path. Its 'path.toString()' value that you posted. And makes a lot of sense. Compare with 'pdfFile.getAbsolutePath();'. Post that value too please.

Comment: **pdfFile** in the above code, fetches this value -> /storage/emulated/0/Download/2019_10_22_03_37_25_pm5906.pdf  which is correct but I think the problem arises when this value in converted into content:// that is from file:/// which is no longer allowed in Android PIE

Comment: I am using that, code snippet is provided in the question (2nd snippet). Although I might be screwing up there not knowing, particularly the path of the dile is where the problem is when it is converted into content://, that's my guess

Comment: "which I think is the problem" -- no, that `Uri` looks typical for `FileProvider`. Try a few different PDF viewers, as not all (yet) support `content` `Uri` values. Or, write a test to confirm that you can read the content from the `Uri` yourself.

Comment: I will run it on my actual phone and see, so far running on emulator only